# Android : Display data from sqlite using Cursor Adapter

Tags: java, android

I am making an application where data is being saved in the database. When I try to run the code, it works ok but when i click the open button "my app crashes". I'm posting the code below please have a look at it

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    VivzHelper vivzHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vivzHelper= new VivzHelper(this);

       // vivzHelper.insertEntry();


      //  vivzHelper.deleteAll();
        SQLiteDatabase data = vivzHelper.getWritableDatabase();




       // Cursor todoCursor = data.rawQuery("Select * from books", null);
       // ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
      //  TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
      //  lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);


    }
    public void openinfo()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowData.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }




}
```

VivzHelper.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Message;

import java.util.HashMap;


/**
 * Created by Akash on 3/13/2016.
 */



public class VivzHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hit_lib1";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "books";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String Name = "Name";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Name+" VARCHAR(25), "+ADDRESS+" VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;



    public VivzHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "Constructor Called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        try {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


            appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "onCreate Called");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {

            appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "" + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

        try {

            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "onUpgrade Called");
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "" + e);


        }

    }


    public void insertEntry()
    {

        try
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();

           // values.put("Messsage", msg);
            values1.put("Name", "Aka");
            values1.put("Address", "Pu");
            values.put("Name", "Pra");
            values.put("Address", "Nid");

            db.insert("books ", null, values1);
            db.insert("books ", null, values);
            appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context, "Inserted Successfully");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            appscreator.com.mydatabase.Message.message(context,""+e);
        }

    }

    public int deleteAll(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getDetails()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("select * from books", null);
    }
}
```

TodoCursorAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Akash on 3/13/2016.
 */
public class TodoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
    // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
    }

    // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
    // such as setting the text on a TextView.
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView tvPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        // Extract properties from cursor
        int body = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        String priority = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("priority"));
        String add = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
        // Populate fields with extracted properties

        tvPriority.setText(String.valueOf(body));
        tvBody.setText(priority);
        address.setText(add);
    }
}
```

ShowData.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by Akash on 3/13/2016.
 */
public class ShowData extends ListActivity {
    private VivzHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        VivzHelper empClick = new VivzHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
        if (cursor != null)
            getListView().setAdapter(
                    new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.display, cursor, new String[]{
                            "uid", "Name", "Address"
                    }, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.add}, 0));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open"
        android:onClick="openinfo"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Study cursors"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The logcat details

```
 03-13 14:37:29.896    2419-2419/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: appscreator.com.mydatabase, PID: 2419
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{appscreator.com.mydatabase/appscreator.com.mydatabase.ShowData}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'uid' does not exist
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'uid' does not exist
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:317)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:92)
            at appscreator.com.mydatabase.ShowData.onCreate(ShowData.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
03-13 14:37:29.904     763-1044/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 appscreator.com.mydatabase/.ShowData
03-13 14:37:29.916     763-1044/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 2 appscreator.com.mydatabase/.MainActivity
03-13 14:37:29.963      763-784/? W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=48208, eventTime=3114859, downTime=610179, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
03-13 14:37:29.974      763-784/? W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=48209, eventTime=3115057, downTime=610179, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
03-13 14:37:30.058     763-1931/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-13 14:37:30.165     763-1931/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-13 14:37:30.165     763-1931/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e824820, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-13 14:37:30.230      763-784/? W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=48210, eventTime=3115112, downTime=610179, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
03-13 14:37:30.760      763-784/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{14c9567f u0 appscreator.com.mydatabase/.ShowData t334 f}
03-13 14:37:31.172    1031-1311/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-13 14:37:31.172    1031-1311/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa083cf40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-13 14:37:32.023      862-862/? W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
03-13 14:37:32.024      862-862/? W/PackageManager﹕ Failure retrieving resources for appscreator.com.mydatabase: Resource ID #0x0
03-13 14:37:32.025    1031-1311/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
03-13 14:37:32.551      763-821/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
03-13 14:37:32.598    2419-2419/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2419 SIG: 9
03-13 14:37:32.632      763-803/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '1b803d87 appscreator.com.mydatabase/appscreator.com.mydatabase.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-13 14:37:32.632      763-803/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '1b803d87 appscreator.com.mydatabase/appscreator.com.mydatabase.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-13 14:37:32.632      763-803/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '3de688dd Toast (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-13 14:37:32.632      763-803/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '3de688dd Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-13 14:37:32.634      763-779/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process appscreator.com.mydatabase (pid 2419) has died
03-13 14:37:32.635      763-780/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{1b803d87 u0 appscreator.com.mydatabase/appscreator.com.mydatabase.MainActivity}
03-13 14:37:32.635      763-780/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '1b803d87 appscreator.com.mydatabase/appscreator.com.mydatabase.MainActivity (server)'
03-13 14:37:32.644     763-1089/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{3de688dd u0 Toast}
03-13 14:37:32.644     763-1089/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '3de688dd Toast (server)'
03-13 14:37:32.693     763-1931/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1b9e300 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9fa1a9f0
03-13 14:37:32.737    1031-1031/? W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=48247, eventTime=3117775, downTime=610179, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
03-13 14:37:32.738    1031-1031/? W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=48248, eventTime=3117834, downTime=610179, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
03-13 14:37:32.789    1031-1031/? W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=48249, eventTime=3117886, downTime=610179, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
03-13 14:37:32.924      763-780/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2419 uid 10064
03-13 14:37:33.891      763-763/? W/NotificationService﹕ Object died trying to hide notification android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@2ebdb9bd in package appscreator.com.mydatabase
```

Comment: you must add the activity on manifest file :      Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {appscreator.com.mydatabase/appscreator.com.mydatabase.ShowData}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes done, i'll update the logcat

Comment: @SofienRahmouniVirtuel i have updated the logcat

Comment: @cricket_007 can u help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `View` object as parameter. Write the method like this :

```
public void openinfo(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowData.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh Did you update the method with the `View` parameter as I mentioned? If still crashing, please update the logcat.

Comment: Yes  how to post logcat it is too big, to post in comments section

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh Edit your post with new logcat details.

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh It is not able to find the activity ShowData, make sure you have declared this activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106160/discussion-between-akashdeep-singh-and-yogesh-umesh-vaity).

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh Add the column called uid in your database table.

Comment: In VivzHelper.java, instead of uid, write _id

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been resolved. I made a mistake in ShowData.java while decalring the fields. I declared UID instead of _id.

Thanks people